# Example on Proving a Recursively Defined Sequence is Convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

So the teacher gave an example on how to prove convergence for a recursively defined sequence.  Unfortunately the example he gave does not really help, and now I am confused more than ever.

So here is the example and a part of the solution.

[image]

My question is, why do we prove that $t_{n} \geq \sqrt2$ ? and why do we take a number $n \geq 2$?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly as said: convergence is implied by **bounded below** and decreasing. So it is enough to prove that these criteria are satisfied. If you want to prove something for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and you are ready with $n=1$ then it remains to prove it for $n\geq2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence $t_n$ is to converge to $l$(a positive real), then $l$ shall satisfy the relation. $2l=l+\frac{2}{l}$. Thus $l=\sqrt{2}$. Now I have to *really* show that $t_n$ is convergent. The monotone convergence theorem says that a bounded and monotone sequence of real numbers is convergent.

If we prove that $t_n\ge \sqrt{2}$ and that $t_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence then it is same as showing that $t_n$ is bounded and $t_1$ is an upper bound (use decreasing sequence) and $\sqrt{2}$ is a lower bound.

In the last line there is a $t_{n-1}$. Since your sequence starts at $t_1$, I have to assume $n\ge 2$ initially.